# Hybrid Auth Facebook login throws exception

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I downloaded Hybrid Auth using composer and copied the index.php and config.php files to root. Then I renamed the index.php file to hybrid.php file. I am only trying to get user's email from facebook.

`Auth.php` is throwing this exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Authentication failed! Facebook
>   returned an invalid user id. in C:\xampp\htdocs\hybrid
>   auth\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\hybridauth\Hybrid\Auth.php:153 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\hybrid
>   auth\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\hybridauth\Hybrid\Auth.php(39):
>   Hybrid_Auth::initialize(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hybrid
>   auth\index.php(6): Hybrid_Auth->__construct('config.php') #2 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hybrid
>   auth\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\hybridauth\Hybrid\Auth.php on line
>   153

Hybrid auth debug file:

https://pastebin.com/i5q4vJhW

- I verified that my baseurl is correct in config.php file.
- I changed the scope attributes value from 'email' to 'email, user_birthday, user_hometown'.

I created a new index.php file as below:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$model = new \Model\App_Model();

$hybridInstance = new Hybrid_Auth('config.php');

$session_identifier = Hybrid_Auth::storage()->get( 'user' );

if (is_null( $session_identifier )) {
    echo "redirect to login";

    try {
        $adapter      = $hybridInstance->authenticate( ucwords('facebook') );
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

        if (empty( $user_profile )) {
            echo "/login/?err=1";
        }

        $identifier = $user_profile->identifier;

        if ($model->identifier_exists( $identifier )) {
            $model->login_user( $identifier );
            echo "welcome";
        } else {
            $register = $model->register_user(
                $identifier,
                $user_profile->email,
                $user_profile->firstName,
                $user_profile->lastName,
                $user_profile->photoURL
            );

            if ($register) {
                $model->login_user( $identifier );
                echo "register and welcome";
            }

        }

    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

My App_Model.php

```
    <?php
namespace Model;

class App_Model {

    private $conn;

    public function __CONSTRUCT() {
        //initialize database
        include('db.php');
        $this->conn = $db;  
    }

    /**
     * Check if a HybridAuth identifier already exists in DB
     *
     * @param int $identifier
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function identifier_exists($identifier)
    {
        try {
            $sql    = 'SELECT identifier FROM users';
            $query  = $this->conn->query($sql);
            $result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

            return in_array($identifier, $result);
        } catch ( \PDOException $e ) {
            die( $e->getMessage() );
        }

    }

    /**
     * Save users record to the database.
     *
     * @param string $identifier user's unique identifier
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $first_name
     * @param string $last_name
     * @param string $avatar_url
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function register_user( $identifier, $email, $first_name, $last_name, $avatar_url )
    {
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (identifier, email, first_name, last_name, avatar_url) VALUES (:identifier, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :avatar_url)";

            $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindValue(':identifier', $identifier);
            $query->bindValue(':email', $email);
            $query->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
            $query->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
            $query->bindValue(':avatar_url', $avatar_url);

            return $query->execute();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create user login session
     *
     * @param int $identifier
     */
    public function login_user($identifier)
    {
        \Hybrid_Auth::storage()->set('user', $identifier);
    }

    /** Destroy user login session */
    public function logout_user()
    {
        \Hybrid_Auth::storage()->set( 'user', null );
    }

    /**
     * Return user's first name.
     *
     * @param int $identifier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName( $identifier )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $identifier )) {
            return;
        }
        $query = $this->conn->prepare( "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE identifier = :identifier" );
        $query->bindParam( ':identifier', $identifier );
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_NUM );

        return $result[0];
    }


    /**
     * Return user's last name.
     *
     * @param int $identifier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName( $identifier )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $identifier )) {
            return;
        }
        $query = $this->conn->prepare( "SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE identifier = :identifier" );
        $query->bindParam( ':identifier', $identifier );
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_NUM );

        return $result[0];
    }

    /**
     * Return user's email address
     *
     * @param int $identifier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail( $identifier )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $identifier )) {
            return;
        }
        $query = $this->conn->prepare( "SELECT email FROM users WHERE identifier = :identifier" );
        $query->bindParam( ':identifier', $identifier );
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_NUM );

        return $result[0];
    }


    /**
     * Return the URL of user's avatar
     *
     * @param int $identifier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAvatarUrl( $identifier )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $identifier )) {
            return;
        }
        $query = $this->conn->prepare( "SELECT avatar_url FROM users WHERE identifier = :identifier" );
        $query->bindParam( ':identifier', $identifier );
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_NUM );

        return $result[0];
    }
}
```

My config.php file:

```
    <?php
/**
* HybridAuth
* http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | http://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
* (c) 2009-2014, HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
*/

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  HybridAuth Config file: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return 
    array(
        "base_url" => "http://localhost/hybrid%20auth/hybrid.php", 

        "providers" => array ( 
            // openid providers
            "OpenID" => array (
                "enabled" => false
            ),

            "Yahoo" => array ( 
                "enabled" => false,
                "keys"    => array ( "key" => "", "secret" => "" ),
            ),

            "AOL"  => array ( 
                "enabled" => false 
            ),

            "Google" => array ( 
                "enabled" => false,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" ), 
            ),

            "Facebook" => array ( 
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "my_app_id_was_here", "secret" => "my_app_secret_was_here" ),
                'scope'   => 'email',
                "trustForwarded" => true
            ),

            "Twitter" => array ( 
                "enabled" => false,
                "keys"    => array ( "key" => "", "secret" => "" ) 
            ),

            // windows live
            "Live" => array ( 
                "enabled" => false,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" ) 
            ),

            "LinkedIn" => array ( 
                "enabled" => false,
                "keys"    => array ( "key" => "", "secret" => "" ) 
            ),

            "Foursquare" => array (
                "enabled" => false,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" ) 
            ),
        ),

        // If you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true.
        // You can also set it to
        // - "error" To log only error messages. Useful in production
        // - "info" To log info and error messages (ignore debug messages) 
        "debug_mode" => true,

        // Path to file writable by the web server. Required if 'debug_mode' is not false
        "debug_file" => "debug",
    );
```

Comment: "*Authentication failed!*" have you verified this is correct? Also the exception is thrown in Auth.php not index.php

Comment: @James Yes, the exception is from Auth.php By verification did you mean am I getting the same error or not ? I am getting the same exception each time.